# use session variables causes poor performance

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, readfile

I have a problem with sessions variables.
I need to store some info (size,size read,...) about the process of read a big file in session variables in order to get this values with jquery ajax method and show to the user the information about the process.

In a php page I have this code:

Read the file, line by line and store(sum) in session variable the size of the line.
**FILE 1 - readfile.php**

```
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
$filesize = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
$readsize = 0;
$linecount = 0;
createSessionValue('filesize', $filesize);
set_time_limit(0);
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $line = fgets($handle);
        if ($line) {
            $readsize += mb_strlen($line);
            createSessionValue('readlines', $readsize);
            $linecount++;
        }
    }
};
```

$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));

And this function:

```
function createSessionValue($sessionField, $sessionValue) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[$sessionField] = $sessionValue;
    session_write_close();    
}
```

In a HTML page i call this php file with ajax:

**File 2 - getSessions.php**

```
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION)) {
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        if(isset($_SESSION['readlines']) && isset($_SESSION['filesize'])){
            $completepercent = round(($_SESSION['readlines'] * 100) / $_SESSION['filesize'],2);
        }
        echo $completepercent . ' % Complete.';
    }
    else {
        echo 'no sessions values found';
    }

    echo '</br>Execution time:' .  ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

This file is called from html page with this jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){             
                window.setInterval(getSessionsValues, 1);
                function getSessionsValues(){
                    $.get("getSessions.php", function(data){
                        //                 alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
                        $('div').html(data);
                    },'html');    
                }
            });
```

The progress work fine, but the performance is very bad with sessions variables:

The results are:

```
Filesize: 732295
Read bytes: 732295
```

- With sessions variables:

  **Processing time: 18.0620 seconds**
- Without sessions variables (I comment the lines that call the function createSessionValue):

  **Processing time: **0.6535 seconds****

Why? what is the best way to control the execution time of a process?

New test:  I lunch the process and open the getProcessStatus.php. the process takes a long time:

**Processing time: 197.5220 seconds**

I'm finally using the solution proposed by @Li-chih Wu.
know my problem is that I get this error in Chrome:
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET).

I'm trying to read a file larger than 500 mb.

Comment: Do you need to start the session so many times? Surely once should be enough.

Comment: Btw you don't have to call `session_start()` everytime you store stuff in a session field - just call it once per request, before doing anything else.

Comment: If i not put session_start() in both files. The ajax request wait until the process ends.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have multi-session requirement...

```
function createSessionValue($sessionField, $sessionValue) {
    file_put_contents("/tmp/$sessionField", $sessionValue);
}
// -------------------
$readlines = file("/tmp/readlines");
$filesize = file("/tmp/filesize");
```

Or you can try this...

```
function createSessionValue($sessionField, $sessionValue) {
    file_put_contents("/tmp/".session_id()."_".$sessionField", $sessionValue);
}
// -------------------
$readlines = file("/tmp/"session_id()."readlines");
$filesize = file("/tmp/"session_id()."filesize");
```

Comment: if I do not get an efficient solution with session variables I thought to use a similar solution. Thank you

Comment: Finally i used your solution mixed with the solution of Matijs but without session(), only save in temp files the status and read this files with ajax. Anyway If a run the ajax page to get the result the process take more time.  If a run the process without ajax call Processing time: 1.3481 seconds, with ajax call more than 20 sec. ¿is normal?

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes running at once and both accessing the same session file.

Most probably the session file is locked by the one process and the other process is waiting for the release of that lock. This may seem strange when the long term process keeps the session file open only for a short time, but it does that many times a second.

Solution: do not write the number of lines every line but say every 100 lines.

Comment: Thank you. I make a mistake...i think the time param in this function are seconds...but its millisec...setInterval(code,millisec,lang)...the session file is locked every 1 millisec...with a 1 sec the performance is better.